# include <x> vs include <x.h>

Tags: c++, header-files

i know we always include a header files, then why do i find some header files like

```
#include<iostream>
```

with no .h extension but some header files like

```
#include<windows.h>
```

with the .h extension and i also tried to add.h to some header files like iostream.h but that didnt work, so what's the difference between adding a .h extension when includeing a file andnot doing this.

thanks for all replies... much appreciated

Comment: it didn't work because `iostream.h` didn't exist on you system.  There is no difference.

Comment: You need to give the exact name of the file. The standard C++ headers do not have a `.h` in the filename. However, there is a file `windows.h`. If you create your own header files, you can name them however you like, but ending them with `.h` is normal convention.

Comment: "Why do some names end in y and others in ie? If I write Jimmy instead of Jimmie, then I get no matches."

Answer (score 5):

It simply depends on the particular header.

The standard library headers (like `<iostream>`) do not have an extension - just use the name.

For other header files (strictly formally, these shouldn't be called "headers," but "included source files"), it's whatever the file's author decided to use. So `windows.h` uses extension `.h`. Boost prefers `.hpp` on its files. `.hh` or `.hxx` is also commonly used for C++, but if the header file's author decides to use `myHeader.IamBob`, you will have to:

```
#include <myHeader.IamBob>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to specify the *exact* file name. There is no "implicit" `.h`. For a standard conforming implementation, the c++ libraries have no extension.

Therefore

```
#include <iostream>
```

is valid and conforming, while

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

may be accepted by *your* compiler (or your neighbours), but it isn't portable nor is it guaranteed to be identical or compatible with `iostream`.

Comment: *And* it's entirely possible that `<iostream.h>` will resolve to something different than `<iostream>` (that was the case with VC 6, for example). The `<iostream.h>`-style headers were pre-standard implementations, with a slightly different interface.

Answer (score 0):

The iostream.h header used to be common before C++ was first standardized in 1998. But since the 98 standard used  instead of , the latter has fallen out of favor (being non-standard and all) and is no longer supported on all platforms. Code that uses it should be considered non-standard legacy code and is not portable.
include `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>` (the latter is deprecated)